# Breaking down a binary number into 4 digits?

Tags: assembly, binary

I need to break down a binary number into 4 decimal digits using assembly.

For example, break down 0010 0110 1001 0010 which is 9874 into '9' '8' '7' '4' and show each on a 7-segment display. I got that display part, I just don't understand the logic/process of breaking it down.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639745/problem-converting-integer-to-ascii-code-in-x86-assembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

divide by 10, capturing the remainder. (modulus operation).   Push the remainder onto a stack or other suitable structure.  Repeat until the quotient is zero.  The remainders that you pushed are the digit values.